# how to implement alljoyn Client & Service at one single Activity (Android)?

Tags: android, eclipse, wifi, android-support-library, alljoyn

I assume that we all using the same source [from the original website.](https://allseenalliance.org/developer-resources/alljoyn/docsdownloads/android)

Alljoyn Library -> Samples -> Android :
-SimpleServices
-SimpleInterface

From your understanding, what is the proper way to implement
alljoyn library into our android development (code).

If let's say, we want to use 1 layout (activity) that do the following works:

1. Broadcast its (device) name
2. Discover other (device) name

Should we put (use) both Interfaces (just like the example) into our one single Activity?
Or perhaps, you've your better solutions? Please share it....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but the sample chat application in the java/samples subdir of both core [downloads](https://allseenalliance.org/source-code) includes both client and server interfaces. It does appear a bit complicated though.